# Comparing two fields of mongo collection using c# driver in mono

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Am completely new to Mongodb and C# driver.

Development is being done using Monodevelop on Ubuntu 14.04 and Mongodb's version is 3.2.10 :

Currently my code has a POCO as below:

```
public class User
{
    public String Name { get; set;}
    public DateTime LastModifiedAt { get; set;}
    public DateTime LastSyncedAt { get; set;}

     public User ()
    {

    }
}
```

Have been able to create a collection and also to add users.

How do I find users, whose LastModifiedAt timestamp is greater than LastSyncedAt timestamp ? Did some searching, but haven't been able to find the answer.

Any suggestions would be of immense help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is not very simple. This should be possible with querysuch as :

```
var users = collection.Find(user => user.LastModifiedAt > user.LastSyncedAt).ToList();
```

But unfortunetly MongoDriver could not translate this expression. 
You could either query all Users and filter on the client side:

```
var users = collection.Find(Builders<User>.Filter.Empty)
                      .ToEnumerable()
                      .Where(user => user.LastModifiedAt > user.LastSyncedAt)
                      .ToList();
```

Or send json query, because MongoDb itself is able to do it:

```
var jsonFliter = "{\"$where\" : \"this.LastModifiedAt>this.LastSyncedAt\"}";
var users = collection.Find(new JsonFilterDefinition<User>(jsonFliter))
                      .ToList();
```

And, yes, you need an Id - Property for your model class, i haven't mentioned it first, because i thought you do have one, just not posted in the question.

Comment: This approach works, but had to add Id field to my POCO. Did it using [BsonId] attribute

Comment: This is completely the wrong approach. You need to add that comparison to your filters and do the work on the db rather than the client.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do it. First lets declare collection:

```
var collection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("CollectionName");
```

Now lets add our project:

```
var pro = new BsonDocument {
                {"gt1", new BsonDocument {
                    { "$gt", new BsonArray(){ "$LastModifiedAt", "$LastSyncedAt" }
                    }
                } },
                {"Name", true },
                {"LastModifiedAt", true },
                {"LastSyncedAt", true }
                };
```

Now lets add our filter:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("gt1", true);
```

We'll aggregate our query:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate(new AggregateOptions { AllowDiskUse = true })
                .Project(pro)
                .Match(filter)
```

Now our query is ready. We can check our query as follow:

```
var query=aggregate.ToString();
```

Lets run our query as follow:

```
var query=aggregate.ToList();
```

This with return the required data in list of bson documents.

This solution will work mongo c# driver 3.6 or above. Please comment in case of any confusion. Hopefully i'll able to explain this.